# Query to obtain the most closer date in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

We would have to find the most aprox date of a current_date. For instance, we have 4 football matches with a distinct dates:

**Table**

```
id   match_id  date
1     69     2011-05-12
2     89     2011-07-18
3     8      2011-08-12
4     5      2011-12-06
```

At first, I think that the best query has to be similar than that expression:

> MIN(DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), date))
>
> > If CURRENT_DATE = 2011-11-25, the result of this query must be id = 4.

Conclusion: We want to obtain the most aprox date from current date rounding down  , any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I have your solution:

Look at this

```
SELECT
match_id
ABS (DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),date))
FROM matches
ORDER BY ABS (DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),date)) ASC 
LIMIT 0,1
```

Good luck buddy!

Comment: Perfect, we were looking for a query like that. Thanks!